¿Cómo se genera la pestaña "Variables" dentro de la sección "Overview" en un reporte de YData Profiling?
Tengo armado el siguiente código para que la biblioteca YData Profiling realie un análisis sobre mi data frame, el código que pude armar es el siguiente

from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
from ydata_profiling.config import Settings
import pandas as pd

# Configuración personalizada básica
custom_config = Settings()  # Usar la configuración por defecto

# Generar el reporte con la configuración exploratoria
profile = ProfileReport(
    promotion,
    title="Reporte de Datos - Employee Promotion Dataset",
    dataset={
        'description': 'Este reporte analiza las promociones de empleados en la base de datos.',
        'author': 'Luis Guillermo Sabas Ortiz',
        'url': 'http://LuisGSabas14.com/'
    },
    config=custom_config,  # Pasar la configuración personalizada
    explorative=True       # Garantiza la habilitación de todas las pestañas exploratorias
)

# Mostrar el reporte en el notebook
profile.to_notebook_iframe()

# Guardar el reporte como archivo HTML
profile.to_file('/content/reporte_personalizado.html')

# Descargar el archivo generado
from google.colab import files
files.download('/content/reporte_personalizado.html')

print("El reporte personalizado se ha generado y guardado como 'reporte_personalizado.html'.")


Si bien el código funciona bien, quiero que el reporte en la sección "Overview" muestre la pestaña adicional "Variables", en esta sección

Tengo entendido que el codigo para agregar la pestaña adicional va mas o menos así

report = ProfileReport(df,dataset={...}, Variables={...})


Cómo soy muy novato todavía, no tengo muy clara de cómo se debe estructurar la sintaxis de la parte "Variables" , pero si alguién pudiera compartir un poco de su expertise, lo agradecería mucho
Saludos

Expertise: lee la documentación. Nadie nace sabiendo exactamente cómo usarlo todo... pero a estas alturas creo que todos sabemos leer. Es cuestión de ir a la documentación y leerla, y estoy 140% seguro de que allí te dice exactamente qué estructura tiene esa parte.
